# Equivalent of Seven Archangels of Zoroastrianism in Vedic Religion?

Tags: demi-gods, angels, vedic

Zoroastrianism and Early Vedic religion are every similar. Scholars even opine that they were one religion and got split into two, or that one originated from the other.

Now in Zoroastrianism there are seven Archangels called [Amesha Spenta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amesha_Spenta), meaning Holy Immortals.

> Amesha Spenta in the Gathas
> Gathic name - Approximate meaning
>
> 1. Spəṇta Mainyu -  Holy/Creative Spirit/Mentality
> 2. [Vohu] Manah  -  [Good] Purpose
> 3. Aša [Vahišta]  -  [Best] Truth / Righteousness
> 4. Xšaθra [Vairya]  -  [Desirable] Dominion
> 5. [Spənta] Armaiti  -  [Holy] Devotion
> 6. Haurvatāt  -  Wholeness
> 7. Amərətāt  -  Immortality

---

### Given that Zoroastrianism is highly similar to early Vedic religion, who are the equivalent of Seven Archangels of Zoroastrianism in Vedic Religion?

Comment: Maybe a stretch, as both share the same adjective, but Asha could be related to [Vasishtha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasishtha).

Comment: Do you have any citations for their similarity? I'm a bit out of the loop, but when looking into Zoroastrianism years ago I believe I remember that they were born from the same cultural milieu, but they were in fact very different and developed in radically different ways. As such, we shouldn't always expect parallels.